# How to delete for every EndOfTheLine in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, programmers-notepad

My file looks as below

```
Number: 31646322588
, disabled: 2
Number: 31654378842
, disabled: 2
Number: 31624883993
, 
Number: 31625010988
, disabled: 2
Number: 31640143191
, disabled: 2
Number: 31622135980
, disabled: 2
```

Expected as below ( that means for every line, I need to press del button)

```
Number: 31646322588, disabled: 2
Number: 31654378842, disabled: 2
Number: 31624883993, 
Number: 31625010988, disabled: 2
Number: 31640143191, disabled: 2
Number: 31622135980, disabled: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do find and replace, check the "Regular Expression" box at the bottom:

Find what: `"\n, disabled"`
Replace with: `", disabled"`

Comment: Not worked, i am able to find "\n, disabled" , but it is not replacing with replace with input-text.

Comment: As you suggested, it replaced like this  

`Number: 31646322588
,disabled: 2
Number: 31654378842
,disabled: 2
Number: 31624883993
, 
Number: 31625010988
,disabled: 2
Number: 31640143191
,disabled: 2
Number: 31622135980
,disabled: 2`

Comment: @UdayKiran: if you mean your final replacements look like `Number: # , disabled: #`, then just change the "Find what" string to `\n , disabled` - notice an added space before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl+h or bring up the find and replace window, set the search mode to regular expression then:

Replace

```
\R*,\R*
```

With

```
,
```